# Flutter app didn't wake up when receive call flutter_callkit_incoming

Tags: android, ios, flutter, call, voip

I'm having one issue when accepting the call from background the app in ios dosen't opened but in android opened, and sometimes return this text in console [BackgroundTask] Background Task 120 ("Flutter debug task"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this

deposit i used
processing and voip permissions in info.plist

note: the process when accept the call it's working in ios
I mean when accept call the app still in background but when open the app i find the changes that did it when accept the call